# Вывод уникальных подмножеств

Tags: python, множества

Есть словарь со списками

```
a = {'seq1':['5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '6', '7', '8', '9'], 
     'seq2':['9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1'],
     'seq3':['5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
     'seq4':['15', '16', '17'],
     'seq5':['18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23'],
     'seq6':['18', '19', '20', '24', '25', '26']}
```

Необходимо

- Найти уникальные списки (список содержащий одни и те же элементы,
  пусть и в иной последовательности **уже не считается уникальным**)
- В уникальных списках найти уникальные подпоследовательности элементов и вывести их

Границы подпоследовательности определяются по схожей последовательности элементов в 2-х сравниваемых уникальных списках (например для списков 1 и 3 граница первой подпоследовательности заканчивается на элементе "1", потому что подпоследовательность ["5","4","3","2","1"] является для указанных списков общей. Две оставшихся подпоследовательности ["6","7","8","9"]["11","12","13"] добавляются в список уникальных подпоследовательностей следом как оставшиеся).

Притом в итоге элементы должны быть в том порядке, **в котором они находились изначально** (в идеале). Т.е. я ожидаю результат:

```
[['5', '4', '3', '2', '1']['6', '7', '8', '9']['11', '12', '13', '14']['15', '16', '17']['18', '19', '20']['21', '22', '23']['24', '25', '26']]
```

Второй список я исключаю так как он, согласно условию, повторяет первый.

Пробовал решить так:

```
import itertools

unique_sets = []

a = {'seq1':["5","4","3","2","1","6","7","8","9"], 'seq2':["9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1"], 'seq3':["5","4","3","2","1","11","12","13","14"], 'seq4':["15","16","17"], 'seq5':["18","19","20","21","22","23"], 'seq6':["18","19","20","24","25","26"]}

b = []

for seq in a.values():
    b.append(seq)

for seq1, seq2 in itertools.combinations(b,2):                                     #searching for intersections 
    if set(seq1).intersection(set(seq2)) not in unique_sets:
        #if set(seq1).intersection(set(seq2)) == set(seq1):
            #continue
        unique_sets.append(set(seq1).intersection(set(seq2)))
    if set(seq1).difference(set(seq2)) not in unique_sets:
        unique_sets.append(set(seq1).difference(set(seq2)))

for it in unique_sets:
    print(it)
```

На выходе получаю это:

```
{'9', '5', '2', '3', '7', '1', '4', '8', '6'}
set()
{'5', '2', '3', '1', '4'}
{'9', '8', '6', '7'}
{'5', '2', '14', '3', '1', '11', '12', '4', '13'}
{'17', '16', '15'}
{'19', '20', '18'}
{'23', '21', '22'}
```

Без заккомментированного куска кода результат ещё хуже.

Плюс ещё эта проблема, когда в множестве элементы неупорядочены. Пробовал сделать то же, но с двумя списками

```
seq1 = set([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
seq2 = set([1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12])
```

На выходе получаю множества где элементы в полученных множествах не меняются местами при каждом запуске программы. Где ошибка?

Заранее благодарен за помощь.

**Update:** узнал, что я не могу применять функции сравнивания множеств на наличие пересечений/различий, т.к. в момент применения функции set() я удаляю информацию о порядке, в котором находятся элементы в конкретном списке.

Comment: словами точно определите, что у вас рассматривается как *"список, содержащий лишь уникальные последовательности чисел."* Откуда такое странное разбиение в результате? (словари неупорядочены в Питоне, поэтому порядок списков не определён) Почему нет `['9', '8', '7', '6']` в результате (а есть только  `['6', '7', '8', '9']`)?

Comment: Да, я немного неточно определил задание - т.к. первые два списка содержат одинаковые элементы, для начала я проверяю сами списки на уникальность. Если два списка содержат одни и те же элементы, я не буду их сравнивать. Таким образом первое условие - различие между списками я сначала устанавливаю по самому их содержанию. Потом в цикле я начинаю сравнивать "уникальные" списки на наличие "уникальных" последовательностей.

Comment: вопрос какой результат вы хотите получить (не ясно почему именно такой результат ожидаете), а не как вы его сейчас пытаетесь получить. Что такое "последовательность" у вас?

Comment: Под "последовательностью" я понимаю то же что и вы. Проблема была в том, что я в начале задания забыл написать, что перед нахождением уникальных последовательностей я ещё и проверяю списки на уникальность. Если два списка содержат одни и те же элементы (невзирая на их расположение), то я беру только один из них. Если бы этой проверки не было, то, как вы и написали ранее, ['9', '8', '7', '6']  тоже бы должен был находиться в списке уникальных последовательностей. Но мне не нужна эта последовательность, т.к. последовательность ['6', '7', '8', '9'] уже была выписана ранее.

Comment: совершенно не ясно по какому признаку  вы "последовательности" выделяете. Почему в ответе больше одной последовательности на список вообще? Почему `['5', '4', '3', '2', '1']['6', '7', '8', '9']`, а не `['5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '6', '7', '8', '9']`?

Comment: Исправил описание - попытался более подробно объяснить задание.

Comment: если у вас есть словарь: `{'a': [1,2], 'b': [2,3], 'c': [3,2,1], 'd': [2,1]}` то какие списки здесь уникальны и почему? Почему seq1 у вас уникальный, а seq2 неуникальный? Вы какой-то порядок ключам задаёте? (по значению ключей, по созданию? или ещё как?)

Answer (score 0):

тулишь первый словарь во временную таблицу с полями

```
{число}, {кол-во}
```

тулишь остальные в ту же таблицу, но при совпадении увеличиваешь поле {кол-во}.

Как все словари притулил, бежишь по таблице, ищешь {кол-во}==1